# what does "17 times out of his nerdy sweater-vest-wearing league" mean?

Tags: expressions

what does "17 times out of his nerdy sweater-vest-wearing league" mean?

I heard it in a drama called "This Is Us".

Kevin was taking about the moment his brother, Randall, got crush on a girl who is Randall's wife now back in college. Randall was a nerd back then. Does Kevin mean she was even nerdier than Randall??

The whole sentence is here.
"It was in college, and, you know, this girl at a party, this really really badass, dreadlocked girl, who was, by the way, like let's be honest 17 times out of his nerdy, sweater-vested-wearing league."

Comment: “17 time out of his nerdy” doesn’t mean anything; you’re misparsing the sentence. It’s “17 times out of his [nerdy, sweater-vest-wearing league]”.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an exaggerated way of stating and/or play-on the slang phrase:

> She's way out of his league: An expression used when a girl is just too hot for you and you have absolutely no chance with her (Urban Dictionary definition).

Your question probably should have not been "What does "17 times out of his nerdy" mean?". Unless the way "nerdy" is being used is somehow contextualized, "17 times out of his nerdy" doesn't actually make any sense because nerdy isn't a noun. I get the feeling your question should have been: "What does 17 times out of his nerdy, sweater-vested-wearing league mean?" which is as stated above:

-> 17 times out of his league: literally way, way out of his league.

-> sweater-vested-wearing league: likely a reference to and joke on the fact that nerds stereotypically wear sweaters and not to be interpreted literally.

Answer (score 0):

### Out of his league

This means "far better than him", in respect of suitability as a partner. Typically people choose partners who rank similarly to them in attractiveness. This is called "assortative mating".

In this case, Kevin is saying that the girl is much more attractive than Randall.

"17 times" is just a made-up number to emphasise how far out of his league she is.

### Nerdy

"Nerdy, sweater-vested-wearing" are just descriptors of the league (or group of men) in which Randall is considered to be in. "Nerdy" means studious and interested in technical things rather than having fun. Going on english.stackexchange.com is a nerdy activity.

### Sweater-vest

I don't know what sweater-vested-wearing means. I think it might be a mistake for "sweater-vest-wearing", meaning that Randall is the type of man who wears sweater-vests. This garment, an armless sweater, is implied to be popular amongst unexciting people. I am from the UK and have never heard of it being called that, but Google Images is definitive!

[image: Sweater-vest images from Google Images]

Putting them together:

> 17 times out of his nerdy, sweater-vested-wearing league.